# Outbound API integration with Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api, marketing-cloud-connect

We have a use case that requires real time integration from Marketing Cloud to an external system. I've done some reading on the APIs to inject data into Marketing Cloud but would like to making outbound calls from Marketing Cloud.

Specifically, I have use case where I need to go through 10 000 + records on a daily basis in a data extension and make an API call to retrieve data from external system A to retrieve a field value (e.g. send a request to a web service end point and receive a response with a value that we would store in a column in a data extension).

I know there is a script activity in Automations and that we can use REST or SOAP but was wondering if anyone had done a similar integration.

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is here?  Are you just asking if anyone has done this before or are you asking for a solution to your 10k record issue?

Comment: Sure, I'm looking for some guidance on the solution for the 10 K Issue... Having to make an outbound callout for each record in a data extension.

Comment: It really sounds like you have most of your answer (REST/SOAP via SSJS Script Activity inside automation). The elegance/capabilities of your solution then would depend on the capability of your external system and how it can interact with SFMC.

Comment: Would you happen to have sample code for a similar use case ?